# jansson library for cross compilation with arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc

Tags: arm, cross-platform, cross-compiling, jansson

I have application that uses jansson library. I want to change our architecture to ARM board. I was searching for how to compile / or source for ARM jansson library, but without any succeed.
Does someone has any idea how to tailor the existing jansson lib to ARM or how to find the source-code for this library and how to compile it suitable for ARM.
I use arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc compiler.

Answer (score 2):

This **thread** seems to answer your question:

https://groups.google.com/d/msg/jansson-users/VDDswPWS490/MS4bD6o0cM0J

```
./configure --build=x86_64-linux --host=arm-poky-linux-gnueabi --target=arm-poky-linux-gnueabi
```

You will need to **alter the host and target lines** to match your cross-compiler. For example, my `cross-gcc` is `arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-gcc`.

Make sure you source your environment before.